# File upload not working

Tags: magento2, file-upload

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p1, when I try to upload any file image (JPG, JPEG, PNG) from CMS or Product Image, it is not working and showing an error.
[image]

pub folder has -R 777 permissions

GD and imagick are enabled

fileinfo support => enabled

file_uploads is on

Comment: Any third party extension install for this functionality then try to disable that one and then check.

Comment: have you found any solutions for this issue, please share.

Comment: @JimitBhavsar It is some time due to corrupt image file so try to upload any other image

Comment: ok, thanks,,, already tried png, jpg image but it's not working.